# laravel model prevent lazy loading throw exception when using "whenLoaded()" for relation in resource

Tags: php, laravel

i recently start using  `Model::preventLazyLoading()`
but it actually throws an error even when the relation is not loaded but it may be loaded sometimes

like this in resource `'discount' => $this->whenLoaded('meta', $this->meta->discount ?? 0),`

laravel version: **9.17.0**

Comment: What error you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `PHP` to resolve your syntax here. It has to load `$this->meta` no matter what, as it has precedence over the `whenLoaded()` method, when `PHP` parsers your code.

```
$this->whenLoaded('meta', $this->meta->discount ?? 0)
```

That is why `whenLoaded()` can take a `closure()` to avoid loading relationship, unless they are actually loaded. This approach will first evaluate the closure after the `whenLoaded()` condition is met.

```
$this->whenLoaded('meta', function () { return $this->meta->discount ?? 0; });
```